# Поиск в базе mysql по массиву в колонке json (mysql 5.7)

Tags: mysql, json

Есть таблица данных mysql 5.7, в которой одно из полей в формате JSON, допустим, такого вида:

```
{"string":"info","array":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Для поиска строки, в колонке JSON которой содержится "info" используется такая структура:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE json->"$.string" = 'info'
```

Вопрос: каким образом совершить выборку строк таблицы, в json массиве которых есть определённые значения, например 1 и 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE
  json_contains(json->"$.array", json_array(1))
  OR json_contains(json->"$.array", json_array(3))
```

Так же можно искать по данным типа:

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   value: "value2",
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   value: "value1",
  }
]
```

=

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE
  json_contains(json->"$[*].id", json_array(1))
```

Comment: `1=1  AND ` можно смело удалять

Comment: ну это для симметрии

Comment: Не для симетрии. Так легче код генерировать для запроса. А здесь  живой человек для живого человека.

Comment: ну это да.. удаляю